# Имя события проблемы:  CLR20r3

Tags: c#

пытаюсь открыть свою программу на сервере 2008. вылазит ошибка

```
     Имя события проблемы:  CLR20r3
Сигнатура проблемы 01:  opcchecker.exe
Сигнатура проблемы 02:  1.0.0.0
Сигнатура проблемы 03:  533b7034
Сигнатура проблемы 04:  OPCChecker
Сигнатура проблемы 05:  1.0.0.0
Сигнатура проблемы 06:  533b7034
Сигнатура проблемы 07:  5
Сигнатура проблемы 08:  3b
Сигнатура проблемы 09:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Версия ОС:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
Код языка:  1049
Дополнительные сведения 1:  0a9e
Дополнительные сведения 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Дополнительные сведения 3:  0a9e
Дополнительные сведения 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Поставил на сервак 4 фреймворк. Программа тоже под 4 фреймворк. на моей 7 запускается, равно как и на хр

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Опишите поподробнее. 
Но проблема в том, что какой-то файл не был найден программой. На это какбэ намекает FileNotFoundException. Может библиотеки какой-то или еще чего программе не хватает.
Описание как дебажить такие проблемы: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx

Comment: на самом деле не было компонента

Comment: Какого компонента не хватало? Напиши ответ, может пригодится кому-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да использовал компоненты quickopc. при установке файлы вроде как коипровались, но системой не виделись. пришлось компоненты отдельно еще ставить